# How to replace array value in PHP

Tags: php

I need to replace below array "[4] => 1 " 4th value based condition. 1 => "Hello" or 0 =>"Hai"

```
Array (
[0] => Array ( [0] => 33 [1] => Test [2] => test2@gmail.com [3] => [4] => 1 )
[1] => Array ( [0] => 36 [1] => Test2 [2] => test3@gmail.com [3] => [4] => 0 )
[2] => Array ( [0] => 37 [1] => Test4 [2] => test4@gmail.com [3] => [4] => 0 )
[3] => Array ( [0] => 38 [1] => Test5 [2] => test5@gmail.com [3] => [4] => 0 )
)
```

Please let me know how to do it in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
{
        $array[$i][4] = ($array[$i][4] == 1);
}
```

This will replace `1` with `true` and anything else with `false`.

Comment: Just for example I ask true or false but I need to replace some name for example if 1 => "Hello" or 0 =>"Hai"

Answer (score 1):

Casting it to a bool will do the trick. For a single element (0th in this case):

```
$arr[0][4] = (bool)$arr[0][4];
```

For all elements, use [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) or a loop:

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    $value[4] = (bool)$value[4];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $subArray){

    switch ($subArray[4]){
        case 1:
            $subArray[4] = "Hello";
            break;
        case 0:
            $subArray[4] = "Hai";
            break;
    }
}
```